# SharePoint Foundation 2010 customising main.xsl to add XPATH query

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, xpath, sharepoint-2010, xslt-1.0

I am trying to get a SharePoint Foundation 2010 list view to display distinct / unique values.

My list view has one column which is a Hyperlink column, it is ordered alphabetically.

One option is to create a customised version of the following file:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\XSL\main.xsl
```

Contents:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
  <xsl:import href="/_layouts/xsl/fldtypes.xsl"/>
  <xsl:import href="/_layouts/xsl/vwstyles.xsl"/>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:decimal-format NaN=""/>
  <xsl:param name="NavigateForFormsPages" />
  <xsl:param name="MasterVersion" select="3"/>
  <xsl:param name="TabularView"/>
  <xsl:param name="NoAJAX"/>
  <xsl:param name="WPQ"/>
  <xsl:param name="RowLimit" select="5"/>
  <xsl:param name="dvt_sortdir" select="'ascending'"/>
  <xsl:param name="dvt_sortfield" />
  <xsl:param name="WebPartClientID"/>
  <xsl:param name="dvt_filterfields" />
  <xsl:param name="dvt_partguid" />
  <xsl:param name="dvt_firstrow" select="1"/>
  <xsl:param name="dvt_nextpagedata" />
  <xsl:param name="dvt_prevpagedata" />
  <xsl:param name="XmlDefinition" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="ViewCounter" select="'1'"/>
  <xsl:param name="View" />
  <xsl:param name="ListUrlDir"/>
  <xsl:param name="List" />
  <xsl:param name="Project"/>
  <xsl:param name="WebTitle"/>
  <xsl:param name="ListTitle"/>
  <xsl:param name="FORM_DISPLAY"/>
  <xsl:param name="FORM_DISPLAY_HTMLURLATTRIBUTEENCODED"/>
  <xsl:param name="FORM_EDIT"/>
  <xsl:param name="FORM_NEW"/>
  <xsl:param name="ENCODED_FORM_NEW"/>
  <xsl:param name="Userid" select="-1"/>
  <xsl:param name="PagePath"/>
  <xsl:param name="PagePathFinal" select="concat($PagePath,'?')"/>
  <xsl:param name="HttpVDir"/>
  <xsl:param name="HttpVDirUniEncoded"/>
  <xsl:param name="HttpPath"/>
  <xsl:param name="HttpHost"/>
  <xsl:param name="PresenceEnabled"/>
  <xsl:param name="FilterLink"/>
  <xsl:param name="FilterLinkNoHost"/>
  <xsl:param name="RecursiveView"/>
  <xsl:param name="WebEditorPreview"/>
  <xsl:param name="NoAnnouncements"/>
  <xsl:param name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo"/>
  <xsl:param name="MoreAnnouncements"/>
  <xsl:param name="AddNewAnnouncement"/>
  <xsl:param name="FreeForm" select="0"/>
  <xsl:param name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible"/>
  <xsl:param name="open_menu"/>
  <xsl:param name="select_deselect_all"/>
  <xsl:param name="IsGhosted" select="'0'"/>
  <xsl:param name="Filter" select="'0'"/>
  <xsl:param name="IsDocLib"/>
  <xsl:param name="WorkspaceAltString"/>
  <xsl:param name="NewGifAltString"/>
  <xsl:param name="LCID"/>
  <xsl:param name="ByText"/>
  <xsl:param name="Modified"/>
  <xsl:param name="Modified_By"/>
  <xsl:param name="SelectedID"/>
  <xsl:param name="idPresEnabled"/>
  <xsl:param name="dvt_RowCount" select="0" />
  <xsl:param name="HasTitleField" select="$XmlDefinition/ViewFields/FieldRef[@Name='Title']"/>
  <xsl:param name="IsHomePageView" select="0" />
  <xsl:param name="ManualRefresh" />
  <xsl:param name="ListRight_AddListItems"/>
  <xsl:param name="GroupingRender"/>
  <xsl:param name="dvt_form_key"/> <!-- -1 means insert-->
  <xsl:param name="InlineEdit"/>
  <xsl:param name="ServerRelativeUrl"/>
  <xsl:param name="OverrideSelectCommand"/>
  <xsl:param name="OverrideFilterQstring"/>
  <xsl:param name="OverrideScope"/>
  <xsl:param name="EcbMode"/>
  <xsl:param name="FieldSortParam"/>
  <xsl:param name="RootFolderParam"/>
  <xsl:param name="AddServerFilterOperationHash"/>
  <xsl:param name="IsPostBack"/>
  <xsl:param name="ShowWebPart"/>
  <xsl:param name="SortQueryString"/>
  <xsl:param name="NoCTX"/>
  <xsl:param name="ShowAlways"/>
  <xsl:param name="EnableAlert"/>
  <xsl:param name="RootSiteUrl"/>
  <xsl:param name="RenderCTXOnly"/>
  <!-- For Relationships-->
  <xsl:param name="HasRelatedCascadeLists" select="0" />
  <xsl:param name="CascadeDeleteWarningMessage"/>
  <!-- For External Lists-->
  <xsl:param name="EntityName" />
  <xsl:param name="EntityNamespace" />
  <xsl:param name="SpecificFinderName" />
  <xsl:param name="LobSystemInstanceName" />
  <xsl:param name="ExternalDataListPermissions" />
  <xsl:param name="RowTotalCount" select="0"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is it possible to add an XPATH query or similar to the above file to do this?

If so where? Please provide an example...

In my custom file, is it possible to include main.xsl to avoid duplicating code?